# Storing Website Data - JSON vs SQL

Tags: php, mysql, json, database

I'm managing a website that is built from the ground-up in PHP and uses AJAX extensively to load pages within the site.

Currently, the 'admin' interface I created stores the HTML for each page, the page's title, custom CSS for that page, and some other attributes in JSON in a file directory (e.g. example.com/hi would have its data stored in example.com/json/hi/data.json).

Is this more efficient (performance-wise) than using a database (MySQL) to store all of the content?

**EDIT:** I understand that direct filesystem access is more efficient than using a database, but I'm not just getting the contents of a file; I need to use json_decode to parse the JSON into an object/array first to work with it. Is the performance hit from that negligible?

Comment: no. Direct FileSystem access > SQL

Comment: Efficiency is going to be only one of the factors here. If generating HTML files works for you, it is surely not the worst way to do things.

Comment: Generating static HTML files won't really work for my AJAX-y interface though. More detail in my comment under Tudor's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thad depends on what you use that data for.

If you only serve 'static' files, with almost the same data all the time, then even static HTML files are recommended for chaching.

If, on the other hand, you process data and display it in multiple forms (searches, custom statistics, etc) then it is **much** better to store it in some kind of DB

Comment: The thing with caching though is that it wouldn't really work right for my AJAX-y interface. The header and footer are always in place, and all the main body content changes when a link is clicked. The data is never really "processed" per se, however.

Answer (score 2):

Your manner doesn't sounds very bad, in fact I used a not-so-far solution before and it does the job pretty good. But you might consider more powerful storage as soon as your admin will grow or the need to separate things arises. Since, there are two ways :

SQL : using relationnal database like Postgre or MySQL

[No-SQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoSQL) : which seems to be more of your interest, here is why.

Considering you're using ajax for communication and json for storage, there's [MongoDB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MongoDB). A no sql approach to storage that use json syntax for querying. There even is an [Interactive Tutorial](http://try.mongodb.org/) for it !

When it comes to performances, no one sounds to be faster. Both engine usually written in C or C++, that is, for best performances. Nevertheless, for a structure as simple as you describe, there's no faster way than direct file access.

Comment: NoSQL sounds like a good alternative as well, but I think my file structure may be simple enough for just direct file access, as you mentioned.